# Python3.4 - Install pyautogui - Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyautogui

I've been trying to install pyautogui for Python 3.4 on my Raspberry Pi 3 for the last 2 hours... I need it because I wrote a touch keyboard application that needs to run on it. On my main machine (elementary OS 0.4 with Python 3.5) I was able to install it without any problems. First I tried `sudo pip install pyautogui` but that only installed the Python 2.7 version of pyautogui. Of course next I tried `sudo pip3 install pyautogui` but that gave me this error:

```
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-hf289jja/pyautogui/setup.py) egg_info for package pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-hf289jja/pyautogui/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
  File "/tmp/pip-build-hf289jja/pyautogui/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File "/tmp/pip-build-hf289jja/pyautogui/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 20, in <module>
    import new
ImportError: No module named 'new'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 17, in

File "/tmp/pip-build-hf289jja/pyautogui/setup.py", line 6, in

```
version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
```

File "/tmp/pip-build-hf289jja/pyautogui/pyautogui/**init**.py", line 114, in

```
from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
```

File "/tmp/pip-build-hf289jja/pyautogui/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 6, in

```
from Xlib.display import Display
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 20, in

```
import new
```

ImportError: No module named 'new'

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hf289jja/pyautogui
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

---

... sorry for the formatting of the above, I couldn't get it to stay inside one code box.

I have no idea what module "new" is. I tried everything else under the sun, such as installing from the official resources: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI and various other guides, with NO results.. I'm kinda loosing my mind right now.

ANY Help is grately appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo pip3 install python3-xlib
sudo pip3 install pyautogui
```

This assumes you have some other python3 libraries already installed, but you will see missing installs in the above if not.